# Tableau Calculated Field Filtering

Tags: visualization, data-visualization, tableau-api

I am struggling with Custom Filter using Calculated Field. 
Below is the screenshot of the same visualized chart.

[image: Screenshot]

What I am struggling is to create a filter where I can give a scale of Correlation, example - I want to show all the age groups and Ethnicity where the Correlation value is between 0.6 and 0.9

I am able to bring in one Measure Value and as you can see, the filter slider is there. But I need that filter to work on all the fields and not just one value. Like a Universal Slider for all the values.

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot set one filter to be used on several measures. However what you can do is create two parameters and use them to filter each measure in relation.

1. create 2 parameters minCorrelation and maxCorrelation with values between 0 and 1 and stepsize of 0.1 (or whatever granularity you need)
2. open one of your filters and go to formula, use a custom formula like `[0-17] > [minCorrelation] AND [0-17] < [maxCorrelation]`
3. repeat that for every measure and the filter will adjust when you change the values for your parameters.

Comment: Yes that can be one option. 
I can also create a Calculated Field with the formula like - 
[0 - 17]>0.5 AND [18 - 25]>0.5 AND [26 - 34]>0.5

and this filters out and shows all the values which are greater than 0.5

But I wanted a slider to that user can adjust the value himself.

Comment: The advantage of a parameter is that you can easily change it without changing the calculations. And your calculated field would only be true of all measures are greater 0.5 in case one isn't, none of your bars would appear

Comment: Yes yes. Calculated field was something which with my basic knowledge of Tableau could solve.

I need something better which will allow the users to change the value / limit themselves.